# How to convert a byteArray to String in PHP?

Tags: php, string, websocket, arrays

I have a `WebSocket` encoder:

```
print_r(frameEncode("How can I convert a byteArray to String in PHP?"));

    function frameEncode($message) {
        $messageBytes = array();
        $messageLength = strlen($message);

        $messageBytes[0] = 129;

        if ($messageLength < 126) {
            $messageBytes[1] = $messageLength;
        } else if ($messageLength <= 65535) {
            $messageBytes[1] = 126;
            $messageBytes[2] = ($messageLength >> 8) & 255;
            $messageBytes[3] = $messageLength & 255;
        } else {
            $messageBytes[1] = 127;
            $messageBytes[2] = ($messageLength >> 56) & 255;
            $messageBytes[3] = ($messageLength >> 48) & 255;
            $messageBytes[4] = ($messageLength >> 40) & 255;
            $messageBytes[5] = ($messageLength >> 32) & 255;
            $messageBytes[6] = ($messageLength >> 24) & 255;
            $messageBytes[7] = ($messageLength >> 16) & 255;
            $messageBytes[8] = ($messageLength >> 8) & 255;
            $messageBytes[9] = $messageLength & 255;
        }

        return pack("C*", $messageBytes) . $message;
    }
```

How can I convert the `$messageBytes` to a string at the end of the function? The array values are simply getting ignored by `pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) like this:

```
call_user_func_array('pack', array_merge(array('C*'), $messageBytes)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return pack("C*", implode(' ', $messageBytes)) . $message;
```